# Предложение на поставку / о поставке

Tags: грамотная-речь, предлоги, лексическая-сочетаемость

Как правильно?
*Посылаем вам наше предложение **на поставку** оборудования.

Посылаем вам наше предложение **о поставке** оборудования.*

Comment: На заметку: если слово "поставка" употребляется с предлогами в разных падежах (на что? **на поставку** — В. п.; о чём? **о поставке** — П. п.), то через слеш такие предлоги писать никак нельзя. Думаю, что правильно так (слеш отделяется пробелами): _Предложение на поставку / о поставке._

Answer (score 1):

Думаю, верны 2 варианта:

Предложение (о чём?) о поставке.

Предложение (по какому вопросу? по чему?) по поставке.

Встречается и "на поставку", но я думаю, это не общелитературное выражение, своеобразный профессионализм, когда слово предложение имеет значение "документ". Если бы это был уже договор, тогда корректно было бы и "на поставку", и "о поставке", а предложение - это только реклама, сведения об условиях  поставки, следовательно, сведения о чём? по вопросу чего? по чему?

Comment: Большое спасибо всем за ответы.Дело в том, что это вопрос из книги Калиновской М.М. "Тестовый практикум по русскому языку делового общения. Бизнес. Коммерция. Внешнеторговая деятельность. Базовый сертификационный уровень". И там сказано, что правильный вариант "НА поставку оборудования". Но. я не понимаю почему? Мне. кажется, что верны оба варианта.

Comment: Видимо, как раз нужно было выбрать профессионализм, а не общелитературное слово, если это профессиональное общение.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Наверное вы правы. Но я всё ещё сомневаюсь. Это учебник для изучающих русский язык. Бизнес, но базовый уровень. Но если нет других объяснений, то ,наверно. это так.